# how to group by in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a Collection with a `field` name and only "Sally" and "Bob" names exist. I want to group my results by this value. I'm currently getting my results and then using `underscore` to perform the `group`. But I should be able to do this with an `aggregate`.
The following is my code

```
  const names = ['Bob', 'Sally'];
  const docs = Collection.find({name: { $in: names}}, { fields: { name:1, age:1}, sort: { name:-1 } }).fetch();

  //How can I do this part in the query above
  const { Bob, Sally } = _.groupBy(docs, "name");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` your condition
- `$group` by `name` and make array called fields and push name and age
- `$sort` by _id means name
- `$replaceWith` to replace object in root, $arrayToObject convert k, v format to object

```
const names = ['Bob', 'Sally'];
const docs = Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: { $in: names } } },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$name",
      fields: { 
        $push: { 
          name: "$name",
          age: "$age"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: [
        [
          {
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$fields"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tSiBiEjQVFL)

Comment: Ah, perfect. Do you know how I can change this to `sort` by `fields`?

Comment: means which fields are you talking about?

Comment: After the `$group` stage - I want to sort the `fields` array of Objects. First by field1, then field2.

Comment: it can not allow to sort by array of object fields  but you can do $sort before the $group..

Comment: I cannot get `$replaceWith` to work. Do you happen to know what to use for the node mongoDB driver as a replacement? I can use `$replaceRoot` but that slightly changes the format

Comment: both will work same when you use `$replaceRoot: { newRoot: { .... } }` look at [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tsmrx2VdsTB). which method you are using in mongodb driver?

Comment: That works! I'm marking this as accepted. But, final output is an array of Objects where the key names are the grouped Ids. Do you know how I can convert this to an Object instead? I'm asking so I don't need to parse the array indices. If it's an Object I can use JS Object Deconstruction. Thanks!

Comment: aggregate() will always return an array, you mean, you need to group it in single object like, `{ Bob: [], Sally: [] }` ?

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/igBA-2yn-yG) if i am not wrong.

Comment: Your playground is exactly what I'm looking for. Getting `'$arrayToObject requires an object keys of \'k\' and \'v\'. Found incorrect number of keys:3` in the Node Mongo driver though. Have you seen this before?

Comment: verify the pipeline stages, in playground, i have changed, and in your error $arraToObject is not getting k and v format array of object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: {
        $in: names
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$name",
      age: {
        $first: "$age"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      name: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it here : [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C0azufh3DSK)